# Durandal: how to cache calls?

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

In my durandal app I need to know if the user is logged in different places. So currently i'm doing a call to get the user state in every views that needs it.

Is possible to do something like this:

```
//login.js

define(function(require) {
 var http = require('durandal/http')
 var isLogged;

 function getLogin() {
 if (isLogged != undefined) return isLogged
 return http.get('/api/login').then(function(data) {
  isLogged = data.logged
  return isLogged
  })
 }

 return {
  getLogin: getLogin
}

//view.js
define(function(require) {
 var login = require('login')
 function vm() {
  var self = this;
  self.isLogged;
  self.activate = function() {
   self.isLogged = login.getLogin()
  }
 }
 return vm
})
```

The above doesn't work because in the view `activate` method I need to return a promise. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This " var http = require('login')", can be dangerous, if the "login" was not defined before, you will get an error! 
I recommend this syntax:
"require('plugin/router', 'login', function (router, login) { ... }"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables for a single web page application using Durandal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984031/global-variables-for-a-single-web-page-application-using-durandal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [guardRouter](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#class/Router/method/guardRoute) function!

This will be triggered in all navigation.

```
// Shell main or other file that runs before any view!
// Define the router guard function!

 require('plugin/router', 'Q', function(router, q){

     var cache = {};

     router.guardRoute = function(instance, instruction) {
         var key = instruction.fragment.toLowerCase();

         return cache[key] !== undefined ?
             cache[key]:
             q($.get(url,data)).then(_setCache, _fail);


         function _fail(/*jqhxr*/) {
            /* do something */
         }

         function _setCache(result) {
             cache[key] = result;
             return cache[key];
         }
     }

 });
```

If you return true, the navigation will proceed! in case of string returned, durandal will navigate into it!

The cache works as you define (check for [javascript memoization](http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/))

About durandal Auth chech [this gitHub](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth) for inspiration.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. I don't want to know how to redirect the user to another page if he isn't logged. I want to know how to create a module that can cache the result of calls - In the first call to the module method it does the API call, next time it only returns me the result of the previous call.

Comment: I should added more information! I have written an example of router.guardRoute, because we can trigger a promise, and wait for resolution, before activating ANY view! 
About the cache, you can use the memoization such as in example (var cache = {};)